# Handling key Ctrl in panel control

Tags: c#, winforms, enums

I want to handle the event when the user press Ctrl, so I am using this :

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;

    if ((msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN) || (msg.Msg == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Down:
                this.Parent.Text = "Down Arrow Captured";
                break;

            case Keys.Up:
                this.Parent.Text = "Up Arrow Captured";
                break;

            case Keys.Tab:
                this.Parent.Text = "Tab Key Captured";
                break;

            case Keys.Control:
                this.Parent.Text = "<CTRL> Captured";
                break;

            case Keys.Alt | Keys.Z:
                this.Parent.Text = "<ALT> + Z Captured";
                break;
        }
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

From: [trap keystrokes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/320584)

But it is not working, in debug mode when I press "Ctrl":

> keyData = Keys.LButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Control

And it does not pass in Keys.Control case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `keyData` has the value `Keys.LButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Control` then none of your cases in the switch statement matches. Certainly `case Keys.Control` does not match because `Keys.LButton | Keys.ShiftKey | Keys.Control != Keys.Control`.

To check for `Keys.Control` you will have to use code like this:

```
if (keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Control))
  this.Parent.Text = "<CTRL> Captured";
```

You cannot use a switch statement to check for flags in an enum. You will have to check for the individual flags which also allows you to handle situations where several modifier keys like <kbd>Control</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> are pressed at the same time.